# Question related to event detection - computer vision

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, image-classification

Steps involved in Event detection.

I am very new to computer vision and I am starting to look into how event detection works. But it really confuses me. I am basically creating a dataset where I am extracting frames from videos and annotating frame images with person, car, animal Etc and I would like to do a event detection to find if there was a crash or not in the image.

My question is that while annotating how can I include the events details? I am using online video annotating tools which allows only to annotate an object in the frame.

Could someone please guide me on this ?

Also on what steps should I follow for event detection ?

Comment: what is it you're asking? recommendations for annotation programs?

Comment: I am aware that objects can be annotated and i am wondering how to capture event annotation and is there a tool which will be useful for me to annotate objects as well as events?

Comment: this question might be more suited to the [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)